# Cannot get XML handler to read Temperaturetags when parseing from web

Tags: android, saxparser

trying to create an android app but the SAXparser won't recognise and display the tempertaure tag data fourther down the document with setting up error and ive tryied everything i can think of to fix it

Code xml file

```
<weatherdata>
    <timetags>
     <item name="date">
        <value>26/07/2011</value>
        <unit/>
        <image/>
        <class>dynamic</class>
        <description>The current date</description>
        </item>
    </timetags>
    <temperaturetags>
      <item name="temp">
         <value>21.8</value>
    </temperaturetags>
 </weatherdata>
```

XML handler

```
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class XMLhandler extends DefaultHandler {

Boolean currentElement = false;
Boolean temperature = false;
String currentValue = null;
public static weatherlist sitesList = null;

public static weatherlist getSitesList() {
return sitesList;
}

public static void setSitesList(weatherlist sitesList) {
XMLhandler.sitesList = sitesList;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


if (localName.equals("weatherdata"))
{
    currentElement = true;
    /** Start*/
    sitesList = new weatherlist();
} if (localName.equals("temperaturetags")) {
    temperature = true;
    /** Start
    sitesList = new weatherlist();*/
} else if (localName.equals("item")) {
/** Get attribute value */
String attr = attributes.getValue("name");
sitesList.setValue(attr);
}

}

/** Called when tag closing*/
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

if (localName.equals("weatherdata"))
    {
    //  currentElement = false;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("temperaturetags")) {
        this.temperature = false;
        sitesList.settemperature(currentValue);
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        sitesList.setName(currentValue);
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("value")){
            sitesList.setitem(currentValue);}
    }

    //  currentElement = false;

/** set value 
if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
sitesList.setName(currentValue);
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("value"))
sitesList.setitem(currentValue);

}*/

/** Called to get tag characters */
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {

if (currentElement) {
currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
currentElement = false;
}
```

code: arraylist

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class weatherlist {

private ArrayList<String> temperature = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();

/** In Setter method default it will return arraylist
* change that to add */

public ArrayList<String> gettemperature() {
    return temperature;
    }

    public void settemperature(String temperature) {
    this.temperature.add(temperature);
    }

public ArrayList<String> getvalue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
this.value.add(value);
}

public ArrayList<String> getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.add(name);
    }

public ArrayList<String> getitem() {
return item;
}

public void setitem(String item) {
this.item.add(item);
}

    }
```

Someone please help!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your item tag

```
<temperaturetags>
      <item name="temp">
         <value>21.8</value>
      </item>
</temperaturetags>
```

Comment: the xml file is kinda generated by weather program and i can't really alter it.